# Import theano with gpu fails, because "out of memory" error

Tags: python, theano, theano-cuda

As soon as I try to import **theano** library I get this error:

```
>>> import theano
ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): ERROR: Not using GPU. Initialisation of device gpu failed:
initCnmem: cnmemInit call failed! Reason=CNMEM_STATUS_OUT_OF_MEMORY. numdev=1
```

Content of my **.theanorc**:

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = gpu
optimizer = fast_run

[lib]
cnmem = 0.9

[nvcc]
fastmath = True

[blas]
ldflags = -llapack -lblas

[cmodule]
mac_framework_link=True
```

I've also tried to run python environment with theano flags, but still the same problem:

```
$ THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu,floatX=float32,lib.cnmem=0.9 python3
```

They're also mentioning similar issue on Theano Github page: [Initialisation of device gpu failed!](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/4302), however they're talking about `float` vs `int` value for `CNMeM`, which I supposed I have correctly setted to `0.9` (for no special reason, I've actually tried `1.0`, `0.95`, `0.5` and some other values, with same results).

#### My setup:

- Mac OS X 10.11.4
- Xcode 7.2 (I had to downgrade it from 7.3)
- Cuda 7.5.19
- Python 3.5.1

### Solution:

First of all I didn't realize that value of `CNMeM` is **% of total memory** and because I was using the gpu with two monitors I actually didn't have much memory to spare, anyway I've tried `0.1` and it works.

The second problem with cuDNN disabled I solved by adding this line to the theano config:

```
optimizer_including = cudnn
```

See this page for more details: [sandbox/cuda/dnn](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/sandbox/cuda/dnn.html)

Comment: So I've tried to run it with **CNMeM** disabled (`cnmem=0`), which doesn't throw an error, but also doesn't solve that. However after importing the theano I'm getting a message the **cuDNN** is not available.
`Using gpu device 0: GeForce GT 750M (CNMeM is disabled, cuDNN not available)`

That's also weird, because I'm pretty sure I have everything ready in the CUDA folder. Apparently this problem is more deeper then I thought.

Comment: It works with GT 940M too. Thanks! imho you should've posted as an answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all I didn't realize that value of `CNMeM` is **% of total memory** and because I was using the gpu with two monitors I actually didn't have much memory to spare, anyway I've tried `0.1` and it works.

The second problem with cuDNN disabled I solved by adding this line to the theano config:

```
optimizer_including = cudnn
```

See this page for more details: [sandbox/cuda/dnn](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/sandbox/cuda/dnn.html)